# Is there a generalized SAT problem for higher-order logics?

Tags: lo.logic, sat, boolean-formulas, philosophy, generalizations

The SAT problem is based upon Boolean expressions, but is there a generalized SAT problem based upon higher order logics?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_quantified_Boolean_formula

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you may be interested in the paper "Higher-Order Quantified Boolean Satisfiability" by Chistikov, Haase, Hadizadeh, and Mansutti (https://doi.org/10.4230/LIPIcs.MFCS.2022.33)